# How to keep a capybara webdriver browser session alive for more than 15 mins?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, capybara, session-timeout

### i.e. How to set webdriver script timeout in Ruby with Capybara.

I am driving a browser application through Ruby with Selenium Webdriver and Capybara

I am polling a website.
If the polling gap is 8 minutes, no problem.  If the polling gap is more than about 10- 15 minutes I find I am logged out of the application the next time I try to visit a page. It seems that the webdriver session is ended.  This does not happen to me when using the application website myserlf - I can stay logged in all day without any actions.  I am not timed out.  This is why I believe the issue is in the webdriver session timeout

This is NOT about the usual `find element` category of timeout that is the genesis of most questions about webdriver timeout.  This is the timeout for the *session* itself.

I create the webdriver session with

```
@session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome)
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this is related to the issue with Chrome 74 when being controlled by chromedriver that it loses cookies randomly.  It had only been reported in headless mode though - are you running headless?  Can you try Chrome 75 since the issue was fixed there.